# CodeIgniter Multiple Sub-Functions or Methods on Same Controller Class?

Tags: php, function, codeigniter, class, controller

I'm new to OOP.

I would like to have these different methods (page, menu, widget) under render functions. They are all in `MY_Controller.php` class. Can you show me an example how to implement this? Just like the built in `$this->parser->parse();` I want to create something similar...

```
public function render('something')
{
    // page() related stuff;
    // menu() related stuff;
    // widget() related stuff;
}
```

`$this->render->page('something');`

`$this->render->menu('something');`

`$this->render->widget('something');`

Is this even possible? I know how to create `$this->render_page();` or `$this->render_widget();` and so on but I think the previous way is more feasible and good for the eyes, some more can group them together for easy maintenance. Do I need to do that way or just simply create different functions?

Comment: I don't understand your "question" it seems like you've already got it figured out. Move the functions into a model and out of ci controller and populate them as you wish.

Comment: Hi @Alex what I meant was, I want to be able to call the function from $this->render->page(); instead of $this->render_page(); because i will also make another “submethods” called menu and widget. How do I do that?

Comment: Oic, so do u think it’s better to use model? Because i thought by rendering pages the logic must be in controller since model is only used for database stuff, im not getting the info from database but just building/rendering the stuff i need from a controller return and send them to views...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"do u think it’s better to use model?"

Traditionally models mainly have to do with databases, however (the way I see it) is that you have either a library or a model to choose from (in CI) when you are going with an OOP approach.

Libraries are more meant to be loosely coupled from your application and drag and drop from CI app to CI app.

Sometimes a model that might be a good idea when you are dealing with logic that is tightly linked to your current application: like header/footers with specific variables that are unlikely to be useful for other purposes (e.g. other apps). For example, I have a model that is used for managing everything about a users profile picture from uploading to deleting - that controller methods can utilize while keeping things DRY - it was too short to be a library and too app-specific to be useful as one and I like my controllers to be input/output only so just validation and responses with the rest being handled by a model or library.

So generally if I were you I'd move the functions into a library or model. I think you will find most templating systems for CI are library based. In any case you can't access `$this->render->somemethod()` unless the methods are in a library/model.

---

Also what you want I think has been done quite a lot, a simple google search for "Codeigniter template library" and you get a slew of github libraries.

Like this one: https://github.com/jenssegers/codeigniter-template-library (even has widgets).

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer. You made it clear, I was thinking of doing something more simplified such as the built-in CI template parser, however, I didn't realise it was actually a library instead of a controller. Now, that make sense and my problem is clear. I'm trying to be familiar with the MVC + OOP approach and how to go about to achieve such simple logic if done solely on pure PHP (since we have to follow the framework guidelines/best practices)... I'm accepting this as an answer.

Comment: Glad I could help :)